# Bringing a view to the absolute front (even over alert dialogs)

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I need one view to always be at the forefront, even over alert dialogs.  I figured there might be two ways to achieve this:

1. Somehow create the alert dialog as part of an existing view, instead of being its own activity
2. Some sort of flag on the view to bring it to the front of everything including alert dialogs

Is this possible?  If so how?

Comment: WindowManager with LayoutParams and Flag as `TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR`. Shows over lockscreens too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WindowManager with LayoutParams and Flag as `TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR`. Shows over lockscreens too.

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
params.x = 100; // position on screen (optional)
params.y = 100;
```

Add Views:

```
windowManager.addView(yourView, params);
```

Edit:

To avoid covering LockScreens: remove `TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR` flag and add following:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE
```

For this to work, you will need to add the following permission to your AndroidManifest.xml too:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

You don't need to request it at Runtime on most of devices except Android Marshmallow **6.0.0**. There is a special way to request it than regular requests. It is checked using:

```
if (Settings.canDrawOverlays()) {
    // you have permission
} else {
    // send an intent with action "ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION"
}
```

Comment: Is there a version of this that does not go as far as covering lock screens?

Comment: edited answer to include `TYPE_PHONE` flag, test it.

Comment: Thanks! Marking as answer for now.  I'll test it soon.

Comment: Does the phone option require a different permission?  Getting an exception related to permissions.

Comment: No, that should be it.What is the exception?